# What is my webHDFS url on Azure HDInsight?

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight, webhdfs

New to azure here. I just finished spinning up a new HDInsight instance with a new storage instance on a regular storage account. I'm wondering what my webHDFS url is/where I can retrieve it and how I can access it.

I am not using Azure Data Lake storage. (nearly every link I've found azure related leads to some data lake link)

my hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

core-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>wasb://<my hdinsight storage name>@<my hdinsight name>.blob.core.windows.net</value>
  <final>true</final>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your base webHDFS FileSystem URI should be: `webhdfs://<HOST>:<HTTP_PORT>` where your HOST should be `CLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net` and HTTP_PORT should be 80 by default.

The corresponding HTTP URL has the following format

`http://<HOST>:<HTTP_PORT>/webhdfs/v1/`

Comment: what should the port be? I have tried both 50070 and 50075

Comment: still no dice. Is there anyway to check if its running? am i using the wrong hostname?

Answer (score 0):

Webhdfs port is same as HDFS namenode port, you can override this port using the below property - `dfs.namenode.http-address` default value is 50070.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

When you are accessing webhdfs through curl or browser, you have to give the port number as follows.

`http://<HOST>:<HTTP_PORT>/webhdfs/v1/`

`http://<HOST>:50070/webhdfs/v1/`

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** Azure HDInsight does not support WebHDFS.

You do not need to create an HDInsight cluster to communicate with ADLS using WebHDFS.

1. Azure Storage is not WebHDFS compatible.
2. Azure Data Lake Store is a cloud-scale file system that is compatible with Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) and works with the Hadoop ecosystem. Your existing applications or services that use the WebHDFS API can easily integrate with ADLS.

[image]

**Reference:** [WebHDFS FileSystem APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datalakestore/webhdfs-filesystem-apis)

3. ADLS Gen2 is Hadoop Filesystem compatible and optimized for a cloud scale big data analytics storage and is not WebHDFS compatible.